# Removing title from wp_list_categories()

Tags: php, wordpress, function, customization

I'm trying to remove/replace the title attribute on the category elements used by WordPress. I'm using WordPress 2.9.1, with the following code:

```
<div id="categories">
    <h3>Manufacturers</h3>
        <ul>
            <?php str_replace("title=\"View all posts filed under ","",wp_list_categories('use_desc_for_title=0&exclude=1,2,3,4,5&title_li=&hierarchical=1')); ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

From what I had read this method used to work on older versions (I had never tried it though). I really don't want to hack at the interals of WordPress, or have to use a JavaScript hack, for something so straight forward. Any help is appreciated...

**Update**
below is what is created from the code above...

```
<div id="categories">
<h3>Manufacturers</h3>
<ul>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/crosstrainers/?cat=7" title="View all posts filed under Featured">Featured</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "category elements" for non-WP experts?

Comment: ... and show some of the offending HTML code?

Comment: Categories are (optionally) associated with blog posts, and when displaying them using wp_list_categories() it keeps adding a default title element (e.g. title="View all posts filed under #category" to the anchor it creates. I can't seem to remove or replace the title

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to use the plugin, stripping the code from the [Remove Title Attributes plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-title-attributes/) you can see the main function used in order to remove the titles from the categories..

open your template/function.php file and insert the following...

```
function wp_list_categories_remove_title_attributes($output) {
    $output = preg_replace('` title="(.+)"`', '', $output);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'wp_list_categories_remove_title_attributes');
```

this will add a new filter replacing the out of the wp_list_categories function used by wordpress and replace it with the function above..

in your code example

```
<div id="categories">
  <h3>Manufacturers</h3>
    <ul>
      <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Would output as

```
 <div id="categories">
      <h3>Manufacturers</h3>
        <ul>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/crosstrainers/?cat=7">Featured</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Were the title="", has been stripped out completely.. 
:)

credits to: [Tim Holt & his plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-title-attributes/)

Comment: Thank you very much!! But why use_desc_for_title=0 doesn't work?? http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit of a late answer on an old post but there's a much more simple way which doesn't require plugins or adding to `functions.php`:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
```

or, if using with other customisations to the output:

```
<?php $args = array (
    'title_li'           => __( '' ),
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'child_of'           => 1
);
wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a plugin for that maybe this can help at least looking at the plugin code.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-title-attributes/

Answer (score 3):

This is probably your best option for anyone looking to do this without any functions.php work

Simply add this to your template.

```
                <ul class="nav">
                    <?php wp_list_categories( array(
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'depth' => 1,
                        'title_li' => '',
                        'hide_title_if_empty' => true,
                        'use_desc_for_title'  => 0,
                        'include' => array( 28, 27, 8, 29, 43, 31 )
                    ) ); ?>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, wp_list_categories will include the Category description in the title attribute if there is one, or "View all posts filed under *category*" if there is no description.

I don't like having the whole description in there. This is what I am using in functions.php to customize the title attribute:

```
function custom_categories_title($output) {
    $search = '/title=".+"(.*>)(.+)</i';
    $replace = "title=\"View all articles filed under $2\"$1$2<";
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $output);
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'custom_categories_title');
```

If you simply wanted to remove the title attribute altogether, you could use

```
    $search = '/ title=".+"/i';
    $replace = '';
```